# Take the database's value over the get{} value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have been using the following technique for fudging calculated values in my database.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public ICollection<Line> Lines {get;set;}

    [AlwaysUpdate]
    public Decimal Total { get { return this.CalcTotal; } set{} }

    public Decimal CalcTotal
    {
        get
        {
             return this.Lines.Sum( l => l.Price * l.Quantity );
        }
     }
}
```

This technique allows me to store a total of the invoice in my database, and if Lines change at all, Total is automatically updated and saved thanks to my `[AlwaysUpdate]` attribute.

If I query invoices like so:

```
_repository.Invoices.Select( i => i.Total );
```

Entity framework will go and fetch the DB's total and not call `CalcTotal`.

However, if I do this:

```
_repository.Invoices.ToList().Select( i => i.Total );
```

Entity framework will call `CalcTotal`.

Usually this is the behavior I want, but I have an issue with a certain query now.  I have to use `ToList` to fetch all records into memory, but I don't want to call `CalcTotal` on every item.

Is there a way to change my little hack here to support not calling `CalcTotal` all the time?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't brilliant, but you could

```
public class Invoice
{
    public ICollection<Line> Lines {get;set;}

    private decimal _dbTotal;

    [AlwaysUpdate]
    public Decimal Total { get { return this.CalcTotal; } set{ _dbTotal = value; } }

    public Decimal DBTotal { get { return _dbTotal;} }

    public Decimal CalcTotal
    {
        get
        {
             return this.Lines.Sum( l => l.Price * l.Quantity );
        }
     }
}
```

DBTotal will always return the total stored in the database, so you could write your query against DBTotal?